# Coding 2d physics with rotation

Tags: libgdx, physics

I want to start with 2d games with physics, but not using BOX2D or other physics engines.
I want to make a game like Trial Bike or Hill Climb Racing, with a 2d bike and 2d terrain.

Where can I start? Are there any good tutorials online?
Is hard to make a basic 2d physics engine?

I'm using libGDX.

Comment: A realistic, fast physics engine is hard. Why do you want to make your own and not just use Box2D?

Comment: I agree to noone. Doing this manually can be quite a hustle. For what you are describing you are planning to do, box2d will be awesome. You will get great collision detection as well as allowing the bike to jump etc... using joints you can even simulate the rotating movement of the legs...

Comment: It depends on how realistic you want it to be. If you want to have a realisitc Physic Engine, there are so many things you need to take care about (aerodynamic drag, gravity, mass...). Also the organisation of the code is not that easy (at least i have some problems with that most times). Where to you store the `gravity`? Where do you do collision detection? How should you manage the collision reaction? And ofc there are many other things. Its a good thing to create a Physics Engine to learn something, but don't set your goal to be able to create good games wit hyour engine.